# Derived Class Shared Methods

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, derived-class

I have a function that 2 derived classes use, but the third doesn't, would it make sense to just leave it in the base class, even though one of the 3 derived classes doesn't use it?

The only way I could think of disallowing the third class is to basically create an intermediate class that is derived of the base, then the 2 that use the common function are derived off the second class.

Is it possible to prevent the 3rd class from using the function, while letting the two that are supposed to use it, use it?

Does that just seem to go overboard, I mean as long as I don't "try" to call the function from the 3rd class, it shouldn't be a problem, I just was interested if there was a way to prevent it all together without a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a way to do this directly.  Basically, when you subclass, you're saying the subclass is a more specific version of the base class.

In this case, you're trying to say "the subclass is a more specific version of the base class, `except for the fact that it shouldn't be able to touch XXX`".  That's, in essence, violating the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

The best way to handle this is to add a second base class in your hierarchy, which is I believe the solution you mention.

Basically, make your hierarchy:

```
base
 | \----   subclass without feature available
 |
 \--base+feature
       \--subclass one with specific feature
       \--subclass two with specific feature
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I was envisioning, I was just hoping it wouldn't have to come to that, I just think that the naming I'm using for each of the derived classes works right now, and I'm not sure an appropriate "intermediate" class name would seem quite right...Also not sure if it induces a lot of overhead...

Comment: @onaclov2000: It should really not introduce any overhead.  I would strongly recommend trying to use convention to enforce this (ie: naming), as you're likely to run into issues down the road.  Its amazing how easy it is to forget the conventions, later.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this function virtual.  Then override the function in the 3rd class and throw an exception.  It will prevent developers to use the function in the 3rd class.

Comment: While this technically works, it's not a good idea.  This violates the Liskov Substitution Principle.  When you're using the third class as the base class (which should always be valid), it will have unexpected behavior.

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to have the same function duplicated across 2 classes, and this doesn't change that. I was hoping to condense the function to one "place" then any future modifications (if required) are in one place only, not 2

Comment: @Reed.  I agree with you that it's not a clean solution.  I look at SOLID principals as very good suggestion how things should be implemented.  However, I don't mind to break them if I need.  In build architecture you have building codes but if you look at masterpieces the occasionally break those code.  You must know the principle but it's ok to break them if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @onaclov2000  May be I don't understand the problem but you don't need to duplicate.  Your both classes are going to use the function from the base class.  Only the 3rd class is going to override it.

Comment: Ahhh now I got ya, I was under the impression that virtual meant that the class had to implement, and that it wouldn't be implemented in the base class, thus causing the base classes to each implement. I must have been mistaken!